# In NodeJS, how to read output of a C program?

Tags: c, node.js

In NodeJS (using Electron, so console.log is on the window console), I want to spawn a child process that's a C program, and read/write into its stdio to communicate.

This is the Javascript :

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
var utfEncoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
var utfDecoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");

var process =  spawn("./src/test-c");

process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(utfDecoder.decode(data));
});

model.send = function(s) {
  model.process.stdin.write(utfEncoder.encode(s));
}

console.log(model.process);
```

And the C :

```
int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    printf("ready !");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int a = 0; a < 100; ++a) {
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        printf("I read: %s", buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the "ready !" never appears anywhere.
But it works when the program only prints a message every second :

```
int main() {
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a) {
        printf("ready !");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With this program the message "ready !" appears every second on the window console, but with the first one nothing happens (not even the first message before `scanf`).

What am I doing wrong here ?

EDIT:
At first I tried a bash script in place of the second example, (echo a message every second) but in fact it also works with a C program that writes a message evvery second without reading any input (which is written here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, my problem was that I wasn't including space characters to the C program at the end of the words, like so : `model.send("hey")` instead of model.send("hey\n")`

So the `scanf` was still waiting for the end of the word to proceed.
Also, the `fflush(stdout)` is absolutley necessary if the message is written with `printf`, but not with `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `scanf("%s"...);` you are reading until the end of a line. So you're not going to get each dot individually. You probably want to read only a single character.

Comment: `scanf` here is used to read what is sent by the JS `model.send` method. But I don't even get to know if that works because the JS dosn't read the first `printf`.
I used the bash dots in place of the C program to check if the JS could read its `stdout`. Which it does, but only for the bash dots, and not the C program.

Comment: If you can replicate the problem without the `scanf`, please edit your question. (And if you can't, then please take another look at my answer because it's probably right.)

Comment: I does work when there is no `scanf`, though I didn't know before yoour comment. So I replaced the bash script with the C equivalent in my question. I hope it's more clear now. thanks for your time